# Field name from ID on table 1 but name on other table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird1.5

This is a Firebird database.

First Table

Contacts Company_ID - job_title

Second Table

Client_id - Co_name

In contacts, I want to the job_title field to contain the co_name.

client_id and company_id are the same. Co_name correspond to company_id as well as client_id.

this:

```
UPDATE Contacts 
  SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.co_name 
where company_id in (
    select client_id from clients 
    JOIN Contacts c ON Client_id=company_id where record_status='A')
```

gives me an error as cannot find (clients.co_name)

this other option:

```
UPDATE Contacts 
 JOIN Clients ON Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Client_id 
 SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.Client_name
```

gives me an error on JOIN

Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Contacts
JOIN Clients ON Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Client_id
SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.Client_name
```

Comment: the field to change is 'Job_title'

Comment: problem is on contacts is company ID

Comment: UPDATE Contacts
SET Contacts.Job_title = clients.Co_name
where co_name in
(select co_name from clients where clients.client_id=contacts.company_id)

Comment: For Firebird this isn't valid syntax.

Comment: This is a Firebird database.

First Table

Contacts Company_ID - job_title

Second Table

Client_id - Co_name

In contacts, I want to the job_title field to contain the co_name.

client_id and company_id are the same. Co_name correspond to company_id as well as client_id.


this other option:
UPDATE Contacts JOIN Clients ON Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Client_id SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.Client_name
error on JOIN

Comment: Any suggestions Mark ?

Answer (score 0):

To update a table from another source, you can use [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge), which only works with Firebird 2.1 or higher:

```
merge into Contacts 
  using Clients
  on Contacts.Company_ID = Clients.Client_id
  when matched then update set Contacts.Job_title = Clients.co_name
```

Using `UPDATE` would be possible, but it would get ugly fast because of the lack of support for joined updates, the equivalent query would be something like the code below. I'm not sure if this will work in Firebird 1.5.

```
update Contacts 
  set Job_title = (select Clients.co_name from Client where Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Company_ID)
  where exists (select * from Client where Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Company_ID)
```

This might be a bit inefficient because of the two sub-selects that are evaluated independently.

Comment: @LeoFazzi What is the exact error message, and what are the exact types of the columns, `co_name`, `Job_title`, `Client_id` and `Company_ID`?

Comment: @LeoFazzi What Firebird version are you using, `merge` was introduced in Firebird 2.1

Comment: Hi Mark, the fields are correct: Table Contacts and table Clients  - Columns contacts.company_id and contacts.job_title and then clients.client_id and clients.co_name.  the Error: ISC error code: 335544569 ISC Error Message: Dynamic SQL error SQL error code = -104 token unknown -line 1, char 1 merge

Comment: firebird 1.5.. old I know

Comment: @LeoFazzi I'm not even sure if my alternate solution with the update will work with Firebird 1.5. You should really consider upgrading.

Comment: what error do you got with alternate solution posted by Mark?